# Scikit-learn: MLPClassifier falsely lowers learning rate after accidentally getting low loss early on

Tags: scikit-learn

Getting used to working with scikit-learn and using the MLPClassifier.
I'm pretty new though and didn't dare to file a bug report as I thought it would be a little premature. Also I can't imagine I'm the first one having this problem.

**Question**: should I file a bug report or am I missing a certain functionality of scikit-learn?

**Info upfront**

```
System:
    python: 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
executable: c:\program files\python37\pythonw.exe
   machine: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0

Python deps:
       pip: 19.3.1
setuptools: 40.8.0
   sklearn: 0.21.3
     numpy: 1.17.0
     scipy: 1.3.0
    Cython: None
    pandas: 0.25.0
```

**Description**

Below I copied part of my `stdout` text file and you can see that early on in the solving process `iteration 401` hit a very low loss (around 0.13). After `n_iter_no_change = 50` the learning rate is divided by 5 (= sklearn setting when `learning_rate='adaptive'`). 
The next 50 iterations run from 0.36 to 0.19. It seems, because the values don't get below the value of `iteration 401` the learning rate is divided by 5 again! However the loss was steadily decreasing and a lower learning rate was not required. This goes on for the next 50 iterations as well and so on. The loss stabilises around 15, but the learning rate gets so small that the difference between iterations would not lead to reaching 0.13. Especially because the learning rate kept being divided by 5 until `tol`would be reached. I interrupted the process manually.

**Code**

```
df_train, df_test, labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(df_stack,labels,test_size=0.2)

print('MULTILAYER PERCEPTRON CLASSIFIER')
l = int(len(df_stack.columns)*1.5)
mlpc = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(l,l,l,l,l),activation='tanh',solver='sgd',alpha=0.01,batch_size=1024,
                     learning_rate_init=0.1,learning_rate='adaptive',max_iter=20000,tol=0.00000001,n_iter_no_change=20,
                     warm_start=True,verbose=True)
mlpc.fit(df_train,labels_train)
mlpc_prediction = mlpc.predict(df_test)
print(classification_report(labels_test,mlpc_prediction))
print(confusion_matrix(labels_test,mlpc_prediction))
```

I thought it would have to do something with `warm_start`, but I tried both `True` and `Fasle`, but see the same phenomenon.

I increased the batch size to `512`. This brings down the occurrences, but it still happens.

**Expected**

When the loss is lowering in a steady pace, I don't expect sklearn after `n_iter_no_change` to suddenly divide the learning rate by 5. It was going great! Why does it lower the learning rate?

I feel like when the learning rate is dropped is should take the first newly calculated loss to calculate if the loss decreased by at least `tol`. It clearly doesn't. Instead it compares with the accidentally obtained lower loss from earlier and decides that the new losses aren't lower and decreasing quickly enough, so it divides the learning rate again, making the problem worse. This leads to the learning_rate and the loss difference quickly bottoming out and falsely claiming that the calculation has come to completion.

```
Iteration 331, loss = 0.36277055
Iteration 332, loss = 0.24242866
Iteration 333, loss = 0.22366280
Iteration 334, loss = 0.21882291
Iteration 335, loss = 0.22645550
Iteration 336, loss = 0.20247741
Iteration 337, loss = 0.20114807
Iteration 338, loss = 0.20465412
Iteration 339, loss = 0.35536242
Iteration 340, loss = 0.30490947
Iteration 341, loss = 0.23094651
Iteration 342, loss = 0.21910954
Iteration 343, loss = 0.21982883
Iteration 344, loss = 0.23542610
Iteration 345, loss = 0.19875187
Iteration 346, loss = 0.18705431
Iteration 347, loss = 0.19246917
Iteration 348, loss = 0.21514954
Iteration 349, loss = 0.18808634
Iteration 350, loss = 0.18320747
Iteration 351, loss = 0.20807128
Iteration 352, loss = 0.18040341
Iteration 353, loss = 0.17532935
Iteration 354, loss = 0.21520632
Iteration 355, loss = 0.18205413
Iteration 356, loss = 0.17632098
Iteration 357, loss = 0.29760320
Iteration 358, loss = 0.19014626
Iteration 359, loss = 0.17066800
Iteration 360, loss = 0.16846425
Iteration 361, loss = 0.33112298
Iteration 362, loss = 0.31750713
Iteration 363, loss = 0.19228498
Iteration 364, loss = 0.17457898
Iteration 365, loss = 0.23505472
Iteration 366, loss = 0.16258889
Iteration 367, loss = 0.20449453
Iteration 368, loss = 0.16618323
Iteration 369, loss = 0.25122422
Iteration 370, loss = 0.16605087
Iteration 371, loss = 0.15851253
Iteration 372, loss = 0.15725671
Iteration 373, loss = 0.15626153
Iteration 374, loss = 0.16184306
Iteration 375, loss = 0.27864597
Iteration 376, loss = 0.17242408
Iteration 377, loss = 0.25311388
Iteration 378, loss = 0.16054483
Iteration 379, loss = 0.16586523
Iteration 380, loss = 0.15612684
Iteration 381, loss = 0.15271917
Iteration 382, loss = 0.14338205
Iteration 383, loss = 0.14576599
Iteration 384, loss = 0.14856326
Iteration 385, loss = 0.14906040
Iteration 386, loss = 0.15078332
Iteration 387, loss = 0.16312012
Iteration 388, loss = 0.17348876
Iteration 389, loss = 0.14614085
Iteration 390, loss = 0.24013805
Iteration 391, loss = 0.15991470
Iteration 392, loss = 0.14121736
Iteration 393, loss = 0.13829140
Iteration 394, loss = 0.13611360
Iteration 395, loss = 0.13957503
Iteration 396, loss = 0.34616708
Iteration 397, loss = 0.17156533
Iteration 398, loss = 0.16191005
Iteration 399, loss = 0.14970412
Iteration 400, loss = 0.14138515
Iteration 401, loss = 0.13482772
Iteration 402, loss = 0.14011477
Iteration 403, loss = 0.15109059
Iteration 404, loss = 0.25684779
Iteration 405, loss = 0.17334369
Iteration 406, loss = 0.13719433
Iteration 407, loss = 0.47797963
Iteration 408, loss = 0.36297558
Iteration 409, loss = 0.29520540
Iteration 410, loss = 0.23906590
Iteration 411, loss = 0.22037938
Iteration 412, loss = 0.19925232
Iteration 413, loss = 0.18805823
Iteration 414, loss = 0.25676207
Iteration 415, loss = 0.17797250
Iteration 416, loss = 0.17708130
Iteration 417, loss = 0.16782866
Iteration 418, loss = 0.16829063
Iteration 419, loss = 0.16531369
Iteration 420, loss = 0.16296342
Iteration 421, loss = 0.15146044
Iteration 422, loss = 0.15707462
Iteration 423, loss = 0.23143112
Iteration 424, loss = 0.15225075
Iteration 425, loss = 0.15847755
Iteration 426, loss = 0.43851424
Iteration 427, loss = 0.24816866
Iteration 428, loss = 0.20171329
Iteration 429, loss = 0.17147653
Iteration 430, loss = 0.15560864
Iteration 431, loss = 0.14891353
Iteration 432, loss = 0.14883808
Iteration 433, loss = 0.17718146
Iteration 434, loss = 0.14910944
Iteration 435, loss = 0.14170514
Iteration 436, loss = 0.14725053
Iteration 437, loss = 0.25596943
Iteration 438, loss = 0.15055692
Iteration 439, loss = 0.77150330
Iteration 440, loss = 0.56516046
Iteration 441, loss = 0.52989079
Iteration 442, loss = 0.50608732
Iteration 443, loss = 0.48526388
Iteration 444, loss = 0.47806246
Iteration 445, loss = 0.42537222
Iteration 446, loss = 0.41309122
Iteration 447, loss = 0.57193972
Iteration 448, loss = 0.49888177
Iteration 449, loss = 0.46276178
Iteration 450, loss = 0.43022112
Iteration 451, loss = 0.40696508
Iteration 452, loss = 0.39255343
Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000000 for 50 consecutive epochs. Setting learning rate to 0.004000
Iteration 453, loss = 0.36314323
Iteration 454, loss = 0.34541510
Iteration 455, loss = 0.33897814
Iteration 456, loss = 0.33539953
Iteration 457, loss = 0.32847849
Iteration 458, loss = 0.32762007
Iteration 459, loss = 0.31942027
Iteration 460, loss = 0.31508242
Iteration 461, loss = 0.31028737
Iteration 462, loss = 0.30865291
Iteration 463, loss = 0.31098832
Iteration 464, loss = 0.30240283
Iteration 465, loss = 0.29712414
Iteration 466, loss = 0.29234763
Iteration 467, loss = 0.28786321
Iteration 468, loss = 0.28467107
Iteration 469, loss = 0.27932500
Iteration 470, loss = 0.27823215
Iteration 471, loss = 0.27465911
Iteration 472, loss = 0.26966135
Iteration 473, loss = 0.27443592
Iteration 474, loss = 0.26456298
Iteration 475, loss = 0.25912139
Iteration 476, loss = 0.25674386
Iteration 477, loss = 0.25327641
Iteration 478, loss = 0.24961365
Iteration 479, loss = 0.24648199
Iteration 480, loss = 0.24457187
Iteration 481, loss = 0.24117319
Iteration 482, loss = 0.23953095
Iteration 483, loss = 0.23615554
Iteration 484, loss = 0.23171504
Iteration 485, loss = 0.23032014
Iteration 486, loss = 0.23480823
Iteration 487, loss = 0.22569761
Iteration 488, loss = 0.22518993
Iteration 489, loss = 0.21999668
Iteration 490, loss = 0.21766831
Iteration 491, loss = 0.21681451
Iteration 492, loss = 0.21406469
Iteration 493, loss = 0.21204087
Iteration 494, loss = 0.21655806
Iteration 495, loss = 0.20624473
Iteration 496, loss = 0.20381265
Iteration 497, loss = 0.20019352
Iteration 498, loss = 0.19979185
Iteration 499, loss = 0.19635400
Iteration 500, loss = 0.19456250
Iteration 501, loss = 0.19451135
Iteration 502, loss = 0.19353174
Iteration 503, loss = 0.19693322
Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000000 for 50 consecutive epochs. Setting learning rate to 0.000800
Iteration 504, loss = 0.18334647
Iteration 505, loss = 0.17993619
Iteration 506, loss = 0.17834410
Iteration 507, loss = 0.17733023
Iteration 508, loss = 0.17661048
Iteration 509, loss = 0.17605634
Iteration 510, loss = 0.17543265
Iteration 511, loss = 0.17519766
Iteration 512, loss = 0.17508450
Iteration 513, loss = 0.17384544
Iteration 514, loss = 0.17354200
Iteration 515, loss = 0.17292735
Iteration 516, loss = 0.17314152
Iteration 517, loss = 0.17250877
Iteration 518, loss = 0.17179139
Iteration 519, loss = 0.17357771
Iteration 520, loss = 0.17130067
Iteration 521, loss = 0.17054958
Iteration 522, loss = 0.17130531
Iteration 523, loss = 0.17016965
Iteration 524, loss = 0.16935377
Iteration 525, loss = 0.16923233
Iteration 526, loss = 0.16846157
Iteration 527, loss = 0.16791882
Iteration 528, loss = 0.16763083
Iteration 529, loss = 0.16659641
Iteration 530, loss = 0.16696834
Iteration 531, loss = 0.16627937
Iteration 532, loss = 0.16591833
Iteration 533, loss = 0.16541474
Iteration 534, loss = 0.16490934
Iteration 535, loss = 0.16486146
Iteration 536, loss = 0.16930541
Iteration 537, loss = 0.16466114
Iteration 538, loss = 0.16404731
Iteration 539, loss = 0.16431962
Iteration 540, loss = 0.16332053
Iteration 541, loss = 0.16560544
Iteration 542, loss = 0.16465136
Iteration 543, loss = 0.16252311
Iteration 544, loss = 0.16218103
Iteration 545, loss = 0.16226194
Iteration 546, loss = 0.16065180
Iteration 547, loss = 0.16483378
Iteration 548, loss = 0.16199347
Iteration 549, loss = 0.15987497
Iteration 550, loss = 0.15914196
Iteration 551, loss = 0.15876606
Iteration 552, loss = 0.15996318
Iteration 553, loss = 0.15846688
Iteration 554, loss = 0.15792289
Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000000 for 50 consecutive epochs. Setting learning rate to 0.000160
Iteration 555, loss = 0.15817669
Iteration 556, loss = 0.15622588
Iteration 557, loss = 0.15582773
Iteration 558, loss = 0.15657326
Iteration 559, loss = 0.15611789
Iteration 560, loss = 0.15576958
Iteration 561, loss = 0.15548868
Iteration 562, loss = 0.15531042
Iteration 563, loss = 0.15519508
Iteration 564, loss = 0.15510623
Iteration 565, loss = 0.15495463
Iteration 566, loss = 0.15487093
Iteration 567, loss = 0.15483675
Iteration 568, loss = 0.15473874
Iteration 569, loss = 0.15463415
Iteration 570, loss = 0.15456982
Iteration 571, loss = 0.15445918
Iteration 572, loss = 0.15440402
Iteration 573, loss = 0.15430028
Iteration 574, loss = 0.15425548
Iteration 575, loss = 0.15414637
Iteration 576, loss = 0.15409595
Iteration 577, loss = 0.15404775
Iteration 578, loss = 0.15405658
Iteration 579, loss = 0.15426012
Iteration 580, loss = 0.15396917
Iteration 581, loss = 0.15376704
Iteration 582, loss = 0.15376100
Iteration 583, loss = 0.15361772
Iteration 584, loss = 0.15345492
Iteration 585, loss = 0.15339733
Iteration 586, loss = 0.15335340
Iteration 587, loss = 0.15333112
Iteration 588, loss = 0.15322458
Iteration 589, loss = 0.15338764
Iteration 590, loss = 0.15312139
Iteration 591, loss = 0.15297541
Iteration 592, loss = 0.15292804
Iteration 593, loss = 0.15286791
Iteration 594, loss = 0.15279897
Iteration 595, loss = 0.15274573
Iteration 596, loss = 0.15263508
Iteration 597, loss = 0.15258324
Iteration 598, loss = 0.15296264
Iteration 599, loss = 0.15259672
Iteration 600, loss = 0.15243085
Iteration 601, loss = 0.15233993
Iteration 602, loss = 0.15248246
Iteration 603, loss = 0.15225322
Iteration 604, loss = 0.15211536
Iteration 605, loss = 0.15204409
Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000000 for 50 consecutive epochs. Setting learning rate to 0.000032
Iteration 606, loss = 0.15168847
Iteration 607, loss = 0.15162253
Iteration 608, loss = 0.15159155
Iteration 609, loss = 0.15159935
Iteration 610, loss = 0.15156232
Iteration 611, loss = 0.15154664
Iteration 612, loss = 0.15152027
Iteration 613, loss = 0.15149465
Iteration 614, loss = 0.15148186
Iteration 615, loss = 0.15146001
Iteration 616, loss = 0.15144674
Iteration 617, loss = 0.15143749
Iteration 618, loss = 0.15141525
Iteration 619, loss = 0.15139387
Iteration 620, loss = 0.15138700
Iteration 621, loss = 0.15136696
Iteration 622, loss = 0.15138551
Iteration 623, loss = 0.15135914
Iteration 624, loss = 0.15132832
Iteration 625, loss = 0.15132639
Iteration 626, loss = 0.15131053
Iteration 627, loss = 0.15129199
Iteration 628, loss = 0.15127809
Iteration 629, loss = 0.15125036
Iteration 630, loss = 0.15124654
Iteration 631, loss = 0.15122546
Iteration 632, loss = 0.15121544
Iteration 633, loss = 0.15119239
Iteration 634, loss = 0.15117764
Iteration 635, loss = 0.15116809
Iteration 636, loss = 0.15114747
Iteration 637, loss = 0.15113152
Iteration 638, loss = 0.15111655
Iteration 639, loss = 0.15111040
Iteration 640, loss = 0.15110277
Iteration 641, loss = 0.15109914
Iteration 642, loss = 0.15106607
Iteration 643, loss = 0.15105276
Iteration 644, loss = 0.15104198
Iteration 645, loss = 0.15101848
Iteration 646, loss = 0.15101173
Iteration 647, loss = 0.15099859
Iteration 648, loss = 0.15098257
Iteration 649, loss = 0.15096238
Iteration 650, loss = 0.15095006
Iteration 651, loss = 0.15093467
Iteration 652, loss = 0.15091879
Iteration 653, loss = 0.15090930
Iteration 654, loss = 0.15088202
Iteration 655, loss = 0.15087644
Iteration 656, loss = 0.15086687
Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000000 for 50 consecutive epochs. Setting learning rate to 0.000006
Iteration 657, loss = 0.15078010
Iteration 658, loss = 0.15077711
Iteration 659, loss = 0.15077672
Iteration 660, loss = 0.15077272
Iteration 661, loss = 0.15076686
Iteration 662, loss = 0.15076496
Iteration 663, loss = 0.15076060
Iteration 664, loss = 0.15075905
Iteration 665, loss = 0.15075893
c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py:568: UserWarning: Training interrupted by user.
  warnings.warn("Training interrupted by user.")
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       0.75      0.75      0.75       951
         1.0       0.82      0.81      0.82      1290

    accuracy                           0.79      2241
   macro avg       0.78      0.78      0.78      2241
weighted avg       0.79      0.79      0.79      2241

[[ 715  236]
 [ 240 1050]]
TEST - MLPC
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       0.46      0.50      0.48       416
         1.0       0.71      0.68      0.69       747

    accuracy                           0.61      1163
   macro avg       0.58      0.59      0.59      1163
weighted avg       0.62      0.61      0.62      1163

[[207 209]
 [241 506]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe does not strike me as strange, in fact it seems to be exactly what one would want when training a neural net. When at some point the loss bottoms out and plateaus or otherwise does not decrease or even increase, one can assume that the learning rate is too high, i.e. the big step size causes the optimization to just "bounce around" some local minimum.

I graphed the training loss (counting from first logged iteration), and it indeed jumps around a lot, even "exploding" at some point. This can happen with some optimizers that adapt learning rate per layer when this learning rate becomes too small, or might indicate that your learning rate is too high.

[image]

I used this code to do this:

```py
s = """log string..."""
plt.plot(np.array(re.findall(r"^Iteration \d+, loss = (?P<loss>[\d\.]+)$", s, flags=re.MULTILINE)).astype(float))
plt.title("Training loss")
plt.xlabel("Iteration")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
# Could use a log scale here
#plt.yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

Also, early stopping is often a good strategy, preventing the model from overfitting. You can do this manually, or save the model every nth step allowing you too choose manually, or use some scikit-learn early stopping strategy.